# Displaying the flash after a redirect in express 3.x

Tags: node.js, express

I understand that `req.flash()` has been removed from express 3.x ([source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x)) and it's recommended to use `req.session` directly (ie, `req.session.messages`).

This is not a problem, however I'm having a hard time figuring out how to display this information in the layout after redirects. I've tried something like

```
app.locals.messages = function() { return req.session.messages };
```

but we obviously don't have access to the `req` object.

How can I display the contents of `req.session.messages` after a redirect?

Comment: I can look up my solution in a few hours when I'm home. I believe that I had to resort to writing a middleware that sets `app.locals.messages` using `req.session`.

Comment: That would be awesome. I have no experience writing middleware so seeing your solution would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I've written a NPM package called flashify to fix this.
`https://npmjs.org/package/flashify`

Comment: I actually saw this during my search and will probably end up using it. I'm also interested in learning how to roll my own, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just do:

```
app.use(/* my session middleware */)
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = req.session.messages
  next()
})
```

and you will always have `messages` in your view. It really doesn't have to be anymore complicated than that.

If you want, you can add your own `flash` function.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var session = req.session;
  var messages = session.messages || (session.messages = []);

  req.flash = function(type, message) {
    messages.push([type, message])
  }

  next()
})
```

And in your view just do `message = messages.pop()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning node and finally think I understand what express middleware is.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use connect-flash https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash